# Efficient multiprocessing/multithreading with large files

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I have two large datasets full of hashes I need to do stuff against:

sample1 (roughly 15gb size):

```
    0000002D9D62AEBE1E0E9DB6C4C4C7C16A163D2C
    00000142988AFA836117B1B572FAE4713F200567
    000001BCBC3B7C8C6E5FC59B686D3568132D218C
    000001E4975FA18878DF5C0989024327FBE1F4DF
```

sample2 (roughly 5gb size):

```
    0000002D9D62AEBE1E0E9DB6C4C4C7C16A163D2C
    00000142988AFA836117B1B572FAE4713F200567
    000001BCBC3B7C8C6E5FC59B686D3568132D218C
    000001E4975FA18878DF5C0989024327FBE1F4DF
```

I am currently trying to implement multiprocessing with both of these files iterating over another set of files in a directory like below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hash_path = glob2.glob(r'pathtohashes*.csv')
    sample1 = pd.read_csv(r'pathtosample1hashes.csv', names=['hash'])
    sample2 = pd.read_csv(r'pathtosample2hashes.csv', names=['hash'])
    for file in hash_path:
        jobs = []
        p = multiprocessing.Process(compare_function(file, sample1, sample2))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

The function compares the file against both sample files and outputs to a directory.

How can I make this more efficient? I feel as though I have too many processes with the full data set in memory when I could maintain a single item in memory and just reference it but am unsure as to how to do so. Any tips on how to make this more efficient would be helpful. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using standard unix tools. If you are trying to find common or missing items, be aware of the `comm` (aka `calm`) and `join` commands. They are purpose-built, in C, for exactly this.

Comment: I have the comparison factor done well in my function, I need to be able to scale outwere to scale to say 5000 files in my hash_path

Comment: Are you going to be CPU bound or IO bound? With gigs of files to consider, I'm assuming that disk IO will be the bottleneck.

Comment: I assume CPU bound. I need to call this function up to 5000 times(5000 separate files of smaller size) and I am on a quad core host with 32gb of ram. I may be attempting to go about this in the wrong way. The function isnt just comparison it has many other items inside of it. This function is also being done via a windows host. from my understanding i only need to be able to reference the two large files some how in memory.